# Change color of legend in correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, visualization, correlation

I have done the following visualization of a correlation matrix:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(5,6,7,8)
data <- data.frame(a, b)
M <- cor(data, method = "spearman")
corrplot(M, method = "color")
```

Now, the legend of the variables appears in red, which I would like to change to black. Also, I would like to change the names of the variables.

I have looked around for possible solutions but have found nothing yet. As I am rather new to R, I do not know how to solve this myself. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own `colorRampPalette`:

```
library(corrplot)

# newdata
a <- c(18,82,3,4)
b <- c(5,6,97,89)
data <- data.frame(a, b)

M <- cor(data, method = "spearman")

colnames(M) <- c("AAAAAAAA", "BBBBBBBBBBBB")
rownames(M) <- c("Bla", "BlaBla")
corrplot(M, method = "color", col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","black"))(200))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
M <- cor(data, method = "spearman")
corrplot(M, method = "color",
col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow"))(200),
tl.col=c("black", "black", "black", "black"))
```

- **tl.col** argument allows user to change the color of each variable
- **col** argument allows the user to change the color of the correlation plot

[image]